# JS Click Event Capturing down to SVG instead of button

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

When I create a click event listener on a button, if the SVG is clicked inside the button, the event target is `<use xlink:href="#star-filled"></use>` instead of the element that was registered to the click event.

How do I prevent it from capturing the child as the target element?

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="rp-form-rating-btn">
  <svg class="rp-star-icon rp-star-four" data-rating="4">
    <use xlink:href="#star-filled"></use>
  </svg>
</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var stars = document.querySelectorAll('.rp-form-rating-btn');

for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
   stars[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
     console.log(event.target);
   }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of a `target` to capture `button` instead to `svg`

`currentTarget` will allow you to get the `element` you clicked on!

> **From MDN:** `currentTarget` always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `Event.target`, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var stars = document.querySelectorAll('.rp-form-rating-btn');

stars.forEach(function(stars) {
  stars.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
  }, false);
})
```

```html
<button type="button" class="rp-form-rating-btn">
  <svg class="rp-star-icon rp-star-four" data-rating="4">
    <use xlink:href="#star-filled"></use>
  </svg>
</button>
```