# Svelte on:click has incorrect e.target when using a button with an inline icon

Tags: button, onclick, svelte, svelte-component

I have the following button:

```
<button on:click={setOnAir} type="button" class="input-group-text">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-satellite-dish " />
</button>;
```

But when clicking the inline element containing the icon, the event target gets set to the inline element instead of the button element; `e.target: <i class="fa-solid fa-satellite-dish  s-UJ6DSMQS0zv2"></i>`.

Modifying the on:click to `on:click|self={setOnAir}` disables this behavior, but then there's no event fired at all when clicking the icon. I tried other modifiers as well, without success so far.

Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't just apply to Svelte, this applies to how the event listener and [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing/) works. What you can do is use `currentTarget` instead of `target`.

Here's an answer to a similar question with vanilla JS:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578073/13631113